# Jira mail handler that chooses issue-type based on tag in title

Tags: email, tags, handler, jira, title

I need to enhance a customer's mail handler, so that it changes the default issue-type based on whether it has a [CR], [INC] or [SR] written in the title. Any ideas? So far the documentation I've checked [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email) doesn't seem to be able to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JEMH add-on to do that

Comment: Or if you're extending an existing one, then take a look at the https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Message+Handler+Plugin+Module module